# How can I get part of the following string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have an absolute url /testserver/tools/search.aspx that I store in a variable url.

I want to check if url == /tools/search.aspx without having to use /testserver.

A more complete example would be:

My testserver contains the url http://www.testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx,

but my live server contains the url http://www.liveserver.com/tools/Search.aspx

If I compare a variable url which stores the testserver url to the liveserver url, it will fail, thats why I want to just check the /tools/Search.aspx portion.

Comment: Is your URL `/testserver/tools/search.aspx` or `http://www.testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx` ?

Comment: when I debug and check the AbsoulteUrl is /testserver/tools/search.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (url.ToLower().Contains("/tools/search.aspx"))
{
   //do stuff here
}
```

I would use Contains in case you have a query string, but you could also use EndsWith("/tools/search.aspx") if you don't have query strings.

Comment: "EndsWith" might be a better choice.

Comment: Just curious, what makes EndsWith a better choice.

Comment: @Andrew -- except in the case where you also want it to match  .../search.aspx?name=something.  EndsWith would be better if you were sure that you had the URL without the query parameters.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I think (though I'm not sure) that the str1.EndsWith(str2) routine will look for a direct match against the last (str2.Length) characters of str1. str1.Contains(str2) has to search all of str1 to find any possible match.

Comment: The case of "/tools/search.aspx.something" (not likely but possible).

Comment: Ok, this worked and it is is an option.  Based on the other answers, is this the best one.

Comment: It doesn't have anything after the aspx, so I guess EndsWith would be better right, is it more efficient?

Comment: Since it is a url there is always the odd chance that the user added some random query string, just to try things out.

Answer (score 3):

If your input is of the form `"http://www.testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx"`:

```
var path1 = new Uri("http://www.testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx").AbsolutePath;
var path2 = new Uri("http://www.liveserver.com/tools/Search.aspx").AbsolutePath;
```

Both result in `"/tools/Search.aspx"`.

Using the `Uri` is the best solution if you have to accept any URI, i.e. including those with a query string, fragment identifiers, etc.

---

If your input is of the form "/testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx" **and** you know that all input will always be of this form and valid and contain no other URI components:

```
var input = "/testserver.com/tools/Search.aspx";
var path1 = input.Substring(input.Index('/', 1));
```

Result is `"/tools/Search.aspx"`.

Comment: Up voted because it, rather sensibly, suggests using tried and tested functionality that is provided by the core system libraries. Why would you do anything else?

Comment: What happens if the application is deployed in a virtual folder on the server, as stated in the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Match(url, @"^.*?/tools/search\.aspx\??.*",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success == true
```

If you grab url from Request.PathInfo you won't have the domain anyway...but you question is ambiguous, as you say your have a path /testserver/ in one but not in the urls you provide.

Otherwise, set url from Request.Url.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property [`AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath.aspx), which will give you the path relative the application root. So `"http://host/virtualfolder/page.aspx"` will be `"~/page.aspx"`:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("~/search.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is going to be the host part of the URL I would use the [**System.Uri**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to compare their **absolute paths** (the "tools/Search.aspx" part of the uri).

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //load up the uris
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.testserver.com/tools/search.aspx");            
    Uri matchingUri = new Uri("http://www.liveserver.com/tools/search.aspx");
    Uri nonMatchingUri = new Uri("http://www.liveserver.com/tools/cart.aspx");

    //demonstrate what happens when the uris match
    if (uri.AbsolutePath == matchingUri.AbsolutePath)
        Console.WriteLine("These match");
    //demonstrate what happens when the uris don't match
    if (uri.AbsolutePath != nonMatchingUri.AbsolutePath)
        Console.WriteLine("These do not match");
}
```